# Magento 2 : How To Get Configurable Product's Child Product Id Using Swatch-option?

Tags: magento2, php

I want to get the product id on selecting the swatch option. for that, I have used the code given below. I am getting the error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')" as per the screenshot.

Error Screenshot:-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAsgD.png

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/custom.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
    jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
        selpro();
    });
});
function selpro () {
    var selected_options = {};
    jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
                var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('data-attribute-id');
                var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('data-option-selected');
                if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
                selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
            });

    var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
    var found_ids = [];

            jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
                var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
                    return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
                }
                if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
                    found_ids.push(product_id);
                }
            });
    
    // console.log(found_ids);

    if (found_ids.length) {
        var selected_product_id = found_ids[0];
        jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
        jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id).toggle();
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to change whole code. I will post answer soon. let me prepare it for you

Comment: on which version you are working?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.4.4 version.

Comment: okay posting answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code work for me you can try it.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_Plugin_ConfigurableProduct_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>
 
    <type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_ConfigurableSkuSwitch_Plugin_Magento_Swatches_Block_Product_Renderer_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type=" Vendor \ Extension \Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type;
 
class Configurable
{
 
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $result
    ) {
 
    $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
    $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
            $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
    }
    $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer;
 
class Configurable
{
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable $subject, $result) {
 
        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
 
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
           $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }
        $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/skuswitch': true
            },
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/swatch-skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\skuswitch.js

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
 
        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
        var result = original();
        var simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];
 
            if(simpleSku != '') {
                $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
            }
            return result;
        });
        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\swatch-skuswitch.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
        var updatePrice = targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice;
        targetModule.prototype.configurableSku = $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html();
        var updatePriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(updatePrice, function(original){
            var allSelected = true;
            for(var i = 0; i<this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length;i++){
                if (!$('div.product-info-main .product-options-wrapper .swatch-attribute.' + this.options.jsonConfig.attributes[i].code).attr('data-option-selected')){
                    allSelected = false;
                }
            }
            var simpleSku = this.configurableSku;
            if (allSelected){
                var products = this._CalcProducts();
                simpleSku = this.options.jsonConfig.skus[products.slice().shift()];
            }
            $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
              return original();
        });
 
        targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice = updatePriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Note: this will update SKU on selection you can modify as per your need.

Comment: I want to get description of child products as well, but couldn't with the same approach as above. Please help me to get description too. I'm using Magento 2.4.5.

Comment: Using above code are you able to get child sku? @JasvirSingh

Comment: I got it by using  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($simpleProduct->getId());
       $product->getDescription();