# Get Configurable Child product description on PDP

Tags: configurable-product

Magento 2.4.5 I want to show each product variation's description on PDP for Configurable Product. I got name and sku on PDP, but couldn't get product description on view page. Please help. I want to change it on drop-down select.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what does your current code that gets the name and SKU look like?

Comment: I followed this Answer and got sku and names of child products. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356790/magento-2-how-to-get-configurable-products-child-product-id-using-swatch-opti